# Javascript public method parameters as private vars

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I am trying to figure out how to have a private instance variable on my class that gets set by a parameter of a public method. In this case, though; it seems that outside of somePublicMethod myPrivateVar will be undefined. How can achieve what I am trying to do ?

```
MyClass = function() {
    var myPrivateVar;

    this.somePublicMethod(myPrivateVar) {
        myPrivateVar = myPrivateVar //????
    }

    this.someOtherPublicMethod() {
        somePrivateMethod();
    }

    function somePrivateMethod() {
        myPrivateVar++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're shadowing the `var myPrivateVar` by giving the argument the same name, so only the argument variable is in scope:

```
this.somePublicMethod = function(myPrivateVar) {
    myPrivateVar = myPrivateVar; // sets the argument to itself
}
```

You'll need to give one of them a different name to avoid shadowing:

```
this.somePublicMethod = function(inputVar) {
    myPrivateVar = inputVar;
};
```

Otherwise, you'll need to contain one of them somehow:

```
MyClass = function () {
    var locals = {
        myPrivateVar: null
    };

    this.somePublicMethod = function (myPrivateVar) {
        locals.myPrivateVar = myPrivateVar;
    };

    function somePrivateMethod() {
        locals.myPrivateVar++;
    }
};
```

Comment: This solution works, but it's not too elegant when I have to use a different name for the input variable.

Comment: @prettymuchbryce Elegant or not, you can't declare 2 variables with the same name in different scopes and still reach both. Either rename or contain one (see edit for the latter).

Comment: Okay fair enough. I like the locals = {} solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.myPrivateVar`:

```
this.somePublicMethod = function(myPrivateVar) {
    this.myPrivateVar = myPrivateVar;
}
```

To call the private method within the context of `this`, you can use:

```
this.somePublicMethod = function(myPrivateVar) {
    this.myPrivateVar = myPrivateVar;
    somePrivateMethod.call(this); // pass this as the context of the private method
}

function somePrivateMethod() {
    this.myPrivateVar++;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but won't fit for this specific case. See my updated example to see why.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered taking a slightly different route?

```
var MyClass = function(){
    var bar = "private";
    return {
        setBar: function( newBar ) { bar = newBar; },
        getBar: function() { return bar; }
    }
};
```

When you new-up an instance of this class, the bar property will be private. However, it will still be accessible by the public `setBar` and `getBar` methods.

```
var inst = new MyClass;

console.log( inst.bar ); // undefined
console.log( inst.getBar() ); // 'private'

inst.setBar( 'accessible' );

console.log( inst.getBar() ); // 'accessible'
```